# Data e hora atual no formato timestamp com time zone

Tags: python, datetime, data, timezone

Como posso imprimir essa data no formato timestamp com time zone (timestampz)?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current_time = (datetime.now())
```

Resultado:

> 2019-03-28 15:14:19.108116

Gostaria que retornasse nesse formato:

> 2019-03-28T15:14:19.000Z

Comment: Para evitar longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91689/discussion-on-question-by-maursb-data-e-hora-atual-no-formato-timestamp-com-time) - para prosseguir basta clicar no link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Este formato que você está querendo (`2019-03-28T15:14:19.000Z`) é definido pela norma [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

De qualquer forma, esse `Z` no final é uma informação importante, pois [indica que a data/hora está em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)). E como você quer a data e hora atual em UTC, não pode simplesmente usar [`datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) e achar que estará certo.

Isso acontece porque [`datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) (quando chamado assim, sem parâmetros) usará o fuso horário do sistema para obter os valores da data e hora atual. A minha máquina, por exemplo, está configurada com o Horário de Brasília, o que significa que hoje é 28 de março de 2019, e agora são 17h. Mas se o fuso horário for mudado para o da Alemanha, o horário retornado será **21h**, e se mudar para o do Japão, o resultado será **29** de março às **5** da manhã. Já em UTC, a data e hora atual é 28 de março de 2019 às 20h.

Para obter os valores de data e hora atual em UTC, use [`datetime.utcnow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow), pois este método retorna os valores de data e hora em UTC, independente do fuso horário configurado no sistema.

---

Já para formatar a data usando o formato ISO 8601, use o método [`isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat). O detalhe é que neste caso vai imprimir somente a data e hora, mas não o `Z`. Mas se quiser, pode adicioná-lo manualmente:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z')
```

Nesse caso eu adiciono o `Z` manualmente, mas **só porque eu sei que `utcnow()` retorna a data e hora atual em UTC**.

Se você usar `now()` em vez de `utcnow()` e colocar o `Z` na frente, poderá estar criando uma data e hora errada. Por exemplo, no meu sistema o timezone é o Horário de Brasília e agora são 17h, então o resultado de `datetime.now().isoformat()` seria `2019-03-28T17:00:00.000000`. Se eu colocar o `Z` na frente fica `2019-03-28T17:00:00.000000Z`: 17h **em UTC**, que corresponde a **14h** no Horário de Brasília, e isso não é a data/hora atual (e sim um instante ocorrido 3 horas antes da data/hora atual). Que diferença que uma "letrinha" faz, não?

Adicionar o `Z` manualmente só "faz sentido" usando `utcnow()`, pois aí o resultado estará em UTC. Usar `now()` só funcionará em casos de "coincidência", se o timezone do seu sistema por acaso for UTC, ou algum outro que também use UTC (como o timezone de [Londres quando não está em horário de verão](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london), por exemplo - sim, quando está em horário de verão, Londres está uma hora a frente do UTC, então mesmo os ingleses devem usar `utcnow()`).

Se atentar para os valores corretos de data e hora é importante, ainda mais se você usar valores em UTC (na verdade, em qualquer timezone), pois mudando os valores da data e hora você vai acabar com instantes completamente diferentes. O problema vai **muito** além de somente "colocar um Z no final da string".

---

O código com `isoformat()` acima não coloca o `Z` porque um `datetime` pode ser *naive* ("ingênuo") ou *aware* ("consciente"), e por padrão `utcnow()` e `now()` criam um objeto *naive*.

Basicamente, quando o `datetime` é *naive*, ele não tem nenhuma informação sobre o timezone (fuso horário), já um *aware* possui tal informação. Por isso o método `isoformat()` só retornou a data e hora. O `Z` não foi impresso porque o `datetime` não tem nenhuma informação sobre o timezone, ele não sabe que seus valores de data e hora vieram da "data/hora atual em UTC" retornada por `utcnow()`.

Mas é possível criar um objeto *aware* passando o [`timezone.utc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone.utc) para o método `now()`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

print(datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat())
```

O resultado é:

> 2019-03-28T20:00:00.736820+00:00

O problema é que agora, em vez do `Z`, ele imprime `+00:00`, que é um [*offset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset): a diferença com relação a UTC. No caso, são zero horas e zero minutos, então **`+00:00` é o mesmo que UTC, que é o mesmo que `Z`**. Por isso, se quiser, pode simplesmente fazer um [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
print(datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat().replace('+00:00', 'Z'))
```

Esse `replace` está correto porque `now(timezone.utc)` retorna a data e hora atual em UTC (independente do timezone que estiver configurado no sistema), e por isso o *offset* gerado por `isoformat()` sempre será `+00:00`, que é o mesmo que `Z` (ambos significam "UTC"). Mas se usar `now()` sem parâmetros acontecem os problemas já citados anteriormente.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução para seu problema é utilizar o método `strftime()` da biblioteca `datetime`. O método formata objetos de data através de strings de entrada. Existe uma [tabela](http://strftime.org/) com os formatos específicos para montar a string como desejar.

No seu caso montamos o formato da maneira como é necessário, ficando:

```
'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

O código da transformação ficaria:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current_time = datetime.now()    
f_data = current_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")

print("formated date: "+str(f_data))
```

[Teste funcionando](https://repl.it/@sant0will/BurdensomeLikelyTriggers)

Comment: Fez o que foi pedido, o downvote deveria explicar o motivo

Comment: @Sidon A minha resposta explica o motivo, não comentei antes pq estava escrevendo-a: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/371959/112052

Answer (score 0):

Converta para timezone, substitua o timezone (:-)) por Z, adicione o T.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
current_time = (datetime.now())
print(print(str(current_time)[0:19].replace(' ','T')))
```

Saida (quando eu executei)

```
2019-03-28T16:54:3600Z
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o motivo do downvote? a pergunta pede a saida em um determinado formato, as duas resposta que vc deu negativou, não faz exatamente isso? Sinceramente não consigo entender os criterios do STOpt.

Comment: A minha resposta explica o motivo do downvote, não comentei antes pq estava escrevendo-a: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/371959/112052

Comment: Desculpe, sua resposta nao justifica o motivo do downvote, gostaria de saber qual é o criterio de um downvote aqui no sto em portugues, veja nesse exemplo o que o cara pede: "Formato especifico em um print", 2 respostas são dadas apresentando exatamente isso e as 2 sao negativadas,  e olha que apesar de eu ter editado a resposta, no final vc faz um repĺace do mesmo tipo da  minha primeira versão. :-)

Comment: O timezone.utc faz toda a diferença no meu replace

Comment: Justificou perfeitamente. Só adicionar o Z no final altera o valor - isso descaracteriza uma formatação. A pergunta claramente pedia que desejava ter a **mesma** data/hora no formato específico. E eu gero a data/hora em uma timezone diferente da UTC e apenas insiro o Z no final eu estarei também alterando o valor da data/hora. A data/hora `2019-03-28 17:30:17.836555` **formatada** no padrão específico é `2019-03-28T20:30:17.836591Z`. Perceba a diferença de 3h entre os dois formatos devido ao fato de eu estar na timezone -3. Somente concatenando o `Z` sua data/hora ficaria por 3h errada.

Comment: OK, @AndersonCarlosWoss, Eu estou ciente disso, mas veja o contexto da pergunta, mesmo depois que ele editou ainda continua igual (eqto escrevo esse comentario), ele diz: o resultado: `2019-03-28 15:14:19.108116`, eu gostaria: `2019-03-28T15:14:19.000Z` (apenas um replace no final), veja que embora ele tenha suprimido na edicao, ele pedia a diferença apenas no resultado do `print()`, ou seja para o `print()` não importa de onde vem a str final. Mas ok, vamos tocar em frente.

Comment: @Sidon Talvez o AP tenha feito isso por não saber as implicações de adicionar o Z no final. De qq forma, já que é pra responder, vamos ensinar certo, não é mesmo? :)

Comment: Sim, @hkotsubo, concordo, mas não é pq uma pessoa não teve o mesmo "insight" que vc que ela  esteja "ensinando errado" ou tenha má intenção e  mereça ser punida com downvote, não é? Vejo discussoes parecidas no STOen e acho interessante que parece ser quase unanime a opinião de se punir com dv apenas tentativas de trapaça, baixa qualidade por desleixo ou displicencia, ou seja, quem, no final, não tem a intenção genuina de ajudar. Mas respeito sua opinião.

Comment: @Sidon Até onde sei, respostas erradas (que não dão o resultado correto ou que explicam conceitos de maneira equivocada) merecem negativo sim, independente da intenção. Mas se vc editar a resposta de forma que dê o resultado correto ou que pelo menos coloque um aviso explicando as limitações da solução, ficarei feliz em retirar o voto :)

Comment: O problema @hkotsubo é que eu não consider que o resultado seja incorreto, pq para a pergunta original o resultado era apenas a apresentção o @sant0will teve o mesmo entendimento que eu, eu nem cogitei que ele precisasse de algo além da apresentação de uma string através do `print()`, esse era o contexto original, mas tudo bem, como disse em outro comentário, respeito sua opinião.